# Convert blob into a clob and then reconvert it in java

Tags: java, oracle, groovy, character-encoding, blob

I'm working with **oracle** and **groovy**. I need to convert a **blob** file(could be anything: pdf, txt, ecc..) into a **clob**. Then I need to convert it back into a blob (to let the user of the application see this).
Is there something in **java** that can do this?

I'm stuck at the creation of the **clob**. This is my groovy script.

```
#input RTXBLOBData blobData, String encoding //My input

import java.sql.Clob
import com.webratio.rtx.RTXBLOBData; //My lib
import com.webratio.rtx.blob.BLOBData; //My lib
import com.webratio.rtx.blob.ExternalBLOBData; //My lib
import com.webratio.rtx.blob.ByteArrayBLOBData; //My lib
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

if(encoding == null || encoding == "")
    encoding = "UTF8"

if(blobData == null)
    return null

Charset charset = Charset.forName(encoding)

InputStream is = blobData.openFileInputStream()
InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(is, charset); 
BufferedReader blobData = new BufferedReader(isReader);
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

int i = 0
while((str = blobData.readLine()) != null){
    if(i > 0)
        buf.append("\n");
    buf.append(str);
    i++
}

String result = buf.toString();

return result
```

I think the problem is the **charset** I'm using, is there a **generic charset** I can use?

Some other advices in pl/sql is accepted. (As a last hope)

Comment: Right off the top of my head you could convert the blob to a byte array and then back.  I'm no expert with java, I don't even know what "groovy" is, I do have VB.NET code that converts a image to a byte array for storage in a Oracle Database if you would find that useful.

Comment: @PrescottChartier Thanks for your advice, post it in a fiddle or something so I can have a look. Thanks again.

Comment: So is a groovy solution acceptable or only Java?

Comment: @MikeW Yes, groovy is acceptable too.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what "Groovy" is, but if you convert the blob to a byte array you should be able to store it in a clob.  I have VB.NET code that converts an image to a byte array, it may be useful, see below:

```
' The user is uploading an image, I grab it from the input stream.  Easy enough to get it from a file or database as well.
Dim TheStream As Stream = file1.PostedFile.InputStream
Dim origimage As System.Drawing.Image
' Store the image in a image variable for scaling
origimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(TheStream)

' I need a memory stream to do the conversion
Dim ms2 As New System.IO.MemoryStream
origimage = ScaleImage(origimage, 320, 200) ' Scale image
origimage.Save(ms2, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) ' Save scaled image to memory stream
Dim MyPhoto() As Byte = ms2.GetBuffer ' The scaled image is converted to a byte array
Session("ThePhoto") = MyPhoto ' I put it into the session to retrieve later as there are other things going on before I store the image in the database.
ms2.Dispose()
origimage.Dispose()
```